# From ice core analysis to temperature curves

Tags: paleoclimatology, climatology, data-analysis, reference-request, ice-sheets

In [ice cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_core) a lot of data are measured and analyzed and can be plotted versus depth, for example

- age of layers
- thickness of layers
- concentration of spurious gases
- concentration of solids
- [delta signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9418O)

I am looking for sources where I can find - ideally at one place - the curves that give the values of these quantities versus ice core depth, e.g. like this

[image]

Is there possibly an interactive website where I can even zoom into such curves?

Finally I'd like to know, if there is one set of "equations" which give the estimated (surface?) temperatures and CO<sub>2</sub> concentrations as well as amount of precipitation as functions of the measured data. I imagine such equations must exist – or are they too complicated to write down? (The equations should also give the error range! Side question: Does the error range decrease with time (i.e. increase with depth)?)